# Using bower with Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

When I create a blank Apache Cordova app, I got a directory structure like:

root
    www
    bower.json
    ...

From the project root directory, if I run "bower install ionic --save", the bower dependencies were all created in the project root while I expect them to go to www.

What is the best way use bower with VSTAC projects?

Answer (score 5):

You can create a [.bowerrc file](http://bower.io/docs/config/) at the root that has the key `directory:'www/bower_components'` set, indicating that the files are placed inside `www` instead of the root.

Visual Studio should be able to now download the dependencies inside the `www` folder.

Note that VS2015 also has intellisense when editing bower.json and automatically installs the dependencies too !!

Comment: `directory:'www\bower_components'` caused an error for me.  I had to escape the backslash: `directory:'www\\bower_components'`

Comment: @axemclion, I'll upvote your answer if you fix the backslash error. This caused me a few headaches and caused VS to continually crash.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command:

```
npm install -g "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\Packages\vs-tac"
```

It worked perfect for me.