# Pre Build Tasks with Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I am using bower.json to install dependencies for an Apache Cordova app created from Visual Studio and was wondering if it is possible to run a pre build task somehow in VS 2015 using the new task runner explorer (or another way) to copy just the minified files from bower_components to www\scripts or if my only option is what is listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640513/using-bower-with-visual-studio-tools-for-apache-cordova)?

If it is possible using gulp, please let me know how starting form the blank Cordova app VS template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Visual Studio guidance for [using NuGet with Cordova projects](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-nuget/) actually has something that may help here. That document includes a note about how to setup a `before_prepare` hook to copy NuGet files into the www folder when building. In Cordova `before_prepare` is one hook into the build process that is similar to a Pre Build task.

Comment: This works! Thanks for the great recommendation!
`var path = require('path');
module.exports = function (context) {
    var shell = context.requireCordovaModule('shelljs');
    var src = path.join(context.opts.projectRoot, 'bower_components/angular/angular.min.js');
    var dest = path.join(context.opts.projectRoot, 'www/scripts/angular.min.js');
    shell.cp(src, dest);
};`
`<hook type="before_prepare" src="hooks/copyBowerToWww.js" />`

Comment: Adding a gulpfile.js to the project with gulp tasks in VS 2015 automatically shows up in the task runner explorer to bind tasks to build actions. Not sure why I didn't try this before but looks like that can help here also.